# 12 VDC arc suppression on 12 V solenoid contacts switching a car starter motor on and off

Tags: motor, solenoid, contact

Would anybody be able to advise the best way and components required to minimise contact burn up on a car motor starter solenoid which is being repeatedly opened and closed?

This is a lure machine using a car 12 V starter motor and a 12 V car battery as the power source.

Comment: A solid state replacement? An even higher rated relay?

Comment: Put a few of [these](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=0.1uF+2kV&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_osacat=0&_odkw=0.1uF+5kV) across the contacts in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

The duty cycle of a starter motor solenoid in a vehicle would be very light when compared to that it would be subjected to when used in a lure machine.

Hence the need for its frequent replacement in a lure machine would be the norm rather than the exception.

Commercial arc suppressors would be available for both AC and DC motor applications.

However arc suppressors would not be available for DC motors with locked rotor current exceeding 75A.

Hence the only solution to extend its life would be to opt for a heavy-duty replacement solenoid switch.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what a lure machine is but I sense that it is something with a motor?

You haven't mentioned the power level, but this could be done with a transistor. If you need to go 2 ways then an H-bridge. And then an all important "snubber" or freewheel diode which will handle the current when turning off again and protecting the transistor.